# Installing python ldap for separate installation of python

Tags: python

I've got some issues with installing python ldap to a separate Python installation. Basically Python2.4 should not be removed because the system (linux redhat) relies on it so I got 2.7 installed in /srv/python2.7 in a separate location. It looks as though python-ldap is already installed for 2.7 as I can see some folders and files in /srv/python2.7/bin/build/python-ldap. But when I run my script it complains it can't find the ldap import. When I try to install python ldap again assuming that it wasn't installed properly I get this output below. I mean all the prequisites for installing python ldap are there on the system such as python 2.4+, Openldap, sasl.

Python ldap works fine for 2.4 and I can see the relevant files in /usr/bin/build/python-ldap are the same as 2.7 in /srv/python2.7/bin/build/python-ldap... I'm also calling the correct python interpreter at the top of the script. And also tried using pip to install /srv/python2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/pip install python-ldap but this also failed miserably.

[root@stats python-ldap]# /usr/local/bin/python setup.py install

```
defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
extra_compile_args:
extra_objects:
include_dirs: /opt/openldap-RE24/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/include
library_dirs: /opt/openldap-RE24/lib /usr/lib
libs: ldap_r
running build
running build_py
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
running build_ext
building '_ldap' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.10 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:
/usr/include/sasl/sasl.h:349: warning: function declaration isnât a prototype
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.10 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/ldapcontrol.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/ldapcontrol.o
Modules/ldapcontrol.c: In function âencode_assertion_controlâ:
Modules/ldapcontrol.c:352: warning: implicit declaration of function âldap_create_assertion_control_valueâ
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.10 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/common.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.10 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/constants.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/constants.o
Modules/constants.c: In function âLDAPinit_constantsâ:
Modules/constants.c:155: error: âLDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGEâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/constants.c:155: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Modules/constants.c:155: error: for each function it appears in.)
Modules/constants.c:365: error: âLDAP_CONTROL_RELAXâ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a mismatch between the python-ldap version to be installed and the installed OpenLDAP version. In general you want to install latest python-ldap with a decent version of OpenLDAP. Wild guess: your OpenLDAP installation is too old. You may want to install a newer version of OpenLDAP in a different path and recompile python-ldap using this version or you search for an older python-ldap version fitting your installed OpenLDAP version.