# Centos 5 Python 2.7, Cannot install Python-LDAP

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ldap, centos5

I need to install 
* Python-LDAP
to run under Ptython 2.7

I have a Centos 5.8 system (I cannot upgrade to 6.x).  I currently have Python 2.4 installed and also Python 2.7.  I am using Python 2.7 for development (along with Django).  I have Python-LDAP installed and working under Python 2.4 (it was installed using yum).  I need to install Python-LDAP for use with Python 2.7 (I will also install Django-ldap).  I have been trying for days to do this.  yum only runs under Python 2.4 so I cannot use that.  I downloaded the Python-LDAP source (python-ldap-2.4.13.tar.gz (md5) from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/ but when I try to build it I get errors (see below).

***Does anyone know if/how I can install Python-LDAP for Python 2.7 on Centos 5?***

Error while building:

```
python setup.py build

defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
extra_compile_args:
extra_objects:
include_dirs: /home/sfuller/python-ldap-2.4.13 /usr/lib64/evolution-openldap/include
```

/usr/lib/evolution-openldap/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/include
    library_dirs: /home/sfuller/python-ldap-2.4.13 /usr/lib64/evolution-openldap/lib64 /usr/lib
/evolution-openldap/lib /usr/lib
    libs: ldap_r
    running build
    running build_py
    file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    running egg_info

```
....

warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building '_ldap' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

-fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.13 
-IModules -I/home/sfuller/python-ldap-2.4.13 -I/usr/lib64/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr
/lib/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:0:
/usr/include/sasl/sasl.h:349:5: warning: function declaration isnât a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.13 -IModules -I/home/sfuller/python-ldap-2.4.13 -I/usr/lib64/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/lib/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/ldapcontrol.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/ldapcontrol.o
```

Modules/ldapcontrol.c: In function âencode_assertion_controlâ:
Modules/ldapcontrol.c:352:5: warning: implicit declaration of function âldap_create_assertion_control_valueâ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.13 -IModules -I/home/sfuller/python-ldap-2.4.13 -I/usr/lib64/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/lib/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/common.o

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.13 -IModules -I/home/sfuller/python-ldap-2.4.13 -I/usr/lib64/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/lib/evolution-openldap/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/constants.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/constants.o

Modules/constants.c: In function âLDAPinit_constantsâ:
Modules/constants.c:155:1: error: âLDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGEâ undeclared (first use in
```

this function)
    Modules/constants.c:155:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    Modules/constants.c:365:29: error: âLDAP_CONTROL_RELAXâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

I then looked over at this thread: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ldap/2011q2/002937.html

So I downloaded the latest OpenLDAP and got:

```
./configure
Configuring OpenLDAP 2.4.38-Release ...
...
configure: error: BerkeleyDB version incompatible with BDB/HDB backends
```

Seems like I'm just sinking lower into a black hole...

Comment: After posting this I find:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716524/installing-python-ldap-for-separate-installation-of-python?rq=1

Comment: Which may answer my question..

Answer (score 0):

This worked in `centos 5.10` and `python 2.7.6`. I installed into a `virtualenv`.

I see mentions of `evolution-openldap` in your logs which were in mine when I had the same issue. Those directories are installed by `openldap 2.3x`.

You don't need to build `openldap` from source as there is a version in yum that is new enough to satisfy the version requirement by `python-ldap`.

```
openldap24-libs.i386                 2.4.23-5.el5                     
openldap24-libs.x86_64               2.4.23-5.el5                     
openldap24-libs-devel.i386           2.4.23-5.el5                     
openldap24-libs-devel.x86_64         2.4.23-5.el5
```

To install you should first `yum install openldap24-libs openldap24-libs-devel`.

edit setup.cfg so its `[_ldap]` section so it contains:

```
library_dirs = /usr/lib/openldap24
include_dirs = /usr/include/openldap24
```

Run the build again. (I deleted my old build/ directory, you probably don't need to but give that a shot if the above is not working).